# "bundle install" for Ruby 1.8.7 on Ubuntu Raring Ringtail 13.04

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler, vagrant

I'm not a rubyist and there might be something obvious I'm missing.

I've wrote an application in Ruby 1.8.7, I'm trying to package it in Vagrant (running Raring 13.04), but I've to run "bundle install" to install the requirements and even though gem1.8 does exist, running `bundle install` still install the gems for Ruby 1.9.3. And then my program fails at runtime...

Any idea about how to solve this?

**UPDATE 1**

The related Gemfile (thanks to the first answerers):

```
ruby '1.8.7'

# ...
gem 'trollop'
```

but for `ruby1.8 myfile.rb` an error is raised

```
no such file to load -- trollop (LoadError)
```

After investigation, the problem looks in `bundle install`:

```
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 1.8.7
```

I don't get how to solve the problem.

**UPDATE 2**

After following the advices from @klaffenboeck things have changed. I'm using RVM and have Ruby 1.8.7 when entering in the project folder. Bundler seems to install things correctly, however the require seems to fail... Path problem?

See here for detail about Vagrant / RVM setup: https://rvm.io/integration/vagrant

**UPDATE 3**

Problem solved, I was missing a:

```
require 'rubygems'
```

before all gems (it worked locally but not in Vagrant).

Comment: no, unfortunately... Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: you know what, join me in the chat - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5676/ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bundler will install gems (by default) for whichever Ruby is in your `PATH`.

Try `/usr/bin/env ruby -v`  or `which ruby` to figure out which one that is; my guess is you're running bundler with Ruby 1.8.

Adding

```
ruby '1.8.7'
```

on top of your Gemfile will help diagnose.

Answer (score 1):

Not aware of this problem in general, but try to put the ruby-version at the top of your gemfile:

```
#Gemfile
ruby '1.8.7'

# followed by your gems
```

#### Edit:

this is most likely because your Gemfile.lock states ruby 1.9.3 - run `bundle update`

Comment: Well I've removed the lock file, but bundle keeps echoing the same thing (I've tried the update command too)

Comment: are you using something like rvm or rbenv that could mess with your ruby-version?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `gem uninstall bundler`, then `gem1.8 install bundler`.

Your `bundle` command seems to be running under Ruby 1.9.3. You can verify which ruby executable bundler is using with `head -n 1 $(which bundle)`. You want it to be ruby1.8.